# Как закрыть ненужные окна в правой нижней части интерфейса Blender 2.91.2?

Tags: blender, окно

Как закрыть ненужные окна в правой нижней части интерфейса Blender 2.91.2 ? Жёлтого уголка, как в древних версиях, в углу окон нет. Нагромождение мешает открыть множество функций, сосредоточенных в правой стороне интерфейса. А удалить созданные многосложные фигуры, над которыми работал не один день, жалко(((

Answer (score 1):

1. Навестись между окнами.
2. Когда появится двухсторонняя стрелка ⟷ нажать правой кнопкой.
3. Нажать **Join Areas**.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]